# Express: How to handle an arbitrarily-long route path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How would one handle a situation where an express endpoint consists of an arbitrary number of route "nodes"?

For example, I'm building an app where you can link users to  files and folders of a file system. If you used two endpoints with only one level - one endpoint for all folders and one for all files, you could link to nested structures with duplicate names by using hashes i.e

```
/uploads/files/3Hz1HqT4
/uploads/folders/T4e2zx1
```

But if you wanted to send readable nested links, i.e .

```
/uploads/tomatoes/red.jpg
/uploads/apples/red.jpg
/uploads/directory/anotherDirectory/aThirdDirectory/file.txt
```

...you'd need to be able to create an arbitrary number of routes off of /uploads.

How would you accomplish this, without using express.static? You'd want to be able to control the route per user for security reasons.

Comment: Don't understand the requirements for the problem.  You can use a single route for `/uploads/*` and then use code to parse the rest of the path and decide what to do.

Comment: The idea is that I want to be able to handle requests with paths that can be dynamically created. For instance, if a user made a new sub-folder, how would you then make a route handler for that new folder? It would have to be done on the fly I assume.

Comment: You wouldn't.  You'd make a route handler for the fixed and known part of the path at the beginning and then your code in that handler would look at what comes after and decide what to do.  Remember that all route handlers apply to all users so you don't make route handler for specific users.  Your code has to add user-specific behavior based on who the user is and what else is in the path.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards wildcard routing! This might be what I do, though I worry about things like this: 

http://www.jongleberry.com/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern.html

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.  If you support arbitrary routes (like your question describes), then you can't predefine all routes and then your route handler code has to check if it's a valuable route.  No issue.  Yes, an invalid route would require you to check something to find that it's an invalid route, but so what.  That's how it should work.